# Looking for a way to group together rows so that columns match and numbers of one column are greater than or equal to zero in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My first post here, hope I provide the right info for you to be able to help.

I have a long Python/Pandas program written which works ok but i am looking to fine tune one element of it.

I am working on a project so that items in different physical areas can be consolidated for maximum area optimization.

So I have a list of items with different status', types and areas stored in. Along with a quantity of that item in that particular area. Each area also has an associated quantity which is available to still be stored in there until it is full.

What i would like to do is link the items together so that the items are consolidated together in a way that the area with the least quantity is merged with an area that has that at least that number of packs left available to fill. I also need the status and type to match for the area to be a match.

It would be ideal if this was presented in the form of a data frame so that the dataframe would output a list of possible moves that satisfy the above statement.

see example dataset/code below:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
        'ITEM NUMBER': [100, 105, 100, 100, 100, 100, 105, 105, 105, 105, 100],
        'STATUS': ["OK", "OK", "NG", "NG", "OK", "OK", "OK", "NG", "OK", "OK", "NG"],
        'TYPE': ["RED", "YELLOW", "RED", "BLACK", "RED", "BLACK", "YELLOW", "YELLOW", "RED", "YELLOW", "BLACK"],
        'AREA': ['A01', 'B01', "A02", "A03", "A04", "A05", "B02", "B03", "B04", "B05", "A06"],
        'QUANTITY': [5, 15, 8, 4, 9, 2, 19, 20, 3, 4, 1],
        'PACKS TO FILL': [10, 5, 2, 6, 1, 8, 1, 0, 17, 16, 9]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index("ITEM NUMBER", inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Based on the above conditions, Item 100  from area A04 should merge into area A01 as it has the same item number, status and type as currently stored in A01 and the quantity in area A04 is less than packs to fill in area A01. This is the same for the other two items in the example dataframe below:

```
data = {
        'ITEM NUMBER': [100, 105, 100],
        'STATUS': ["OK", "OK", "NG"],
        'TYPE': ["RED", "YELLOW", "BLACK"],
        'AREA': ['A04', 'B05', "A06"],
        'MOVE TO': ['A01', "B01", "A03"]

}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index("ITEM NUMBER", inplace=True)
print(df)
```

I have previously been using pivot tables to group items together and manually link areas together but this is a long process so would like to automate it if possible.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

```
#create a grouping to get the first items in each group
#do not sort, leave table as is
grouping = (df
           .groupby(['ITEM NUMBER','STATUS','TYPE'],sort = False)
           .agg(move_to=('AREA','first'))
            )

(df
 #set index so i can use the join method
 .set_index(['ITEM NUMBER','STATUS','TYPE'])
 .join(grouping)
 #get the pack to fill value for values in move_to column
 .assign(pack_size = lambda x:  x.loc[x.AREA.eq(x.move_to),'PACKS TO FILL'])
 #we need only rows where quantity is less than pack size
 #and value in area not in move_to
 .query('QUANTITY < pack_size and AREA != move_to')
 .filter(['AREA','move_to'])
 .reset_index([1,2])
 )


              STATUS    TYPE    AREA    move_to
ITEM NUMBER             
 100            NG     BLACK    A06     A03
 100            OK     RED      A04     A01
 105            OK     YELLOW   B05     B01
```

Comment: Thank you, that is just what I was looking for. Do you think there is any way the packs to fill column could be updated if the move had been made. Using this with a real dataset works but there will be duplicate entries of item number listed with moves that would not be possible since the packs to fill value will reduce from the move. It is not the end of the world if not as i could just remove duplicates in excel. Thank you again for your help

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible. Throw in an update to ur question with this use case and let’s c how it goes